# sql_alchemy.create_engine and pd.read_sql throws IndexError: tuple index out of range on first connect

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm obfuscating `USER`, `PASS`, `DB_SERVER` and `DB_NAME`. None of the values of the previous variables contain special characters and they are solely alphanumeric.

I am creating the engine with the following on a linux box connecting to a mssql db:

Throws `IndexError: tuple index out of range`:

```
import sqlalchemy
DRIVER="FreeTDS&PORT=1433&TDS_VERSION=8.0"
sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{USER}:{PASS}@{DB_SERVER}/{DB_NAME}?driver={DRIVER}")
```

The engine is then passed to a pandas [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) call.

However, if I run this on Windows, it is fine:

```
import sqlalchemy
DRIVER='SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{USER}:{PASS}@{DB_SERVER}/{DB_NAME}?driver={DRIVER}")
```

This is the obfuscated stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 515, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1295, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1162, in execute
    *args, **kwargs
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2236, in execute
    connection = self._contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2304, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2338, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    ).exec_once_unless_exception(self.connection, self)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 314, in exec_once_unless_exception
    self._exec_once_impl(True, *args, **kw)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 285, in _exec_once_impl
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 322, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1513, in go
    return once_fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 199, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py", line 2444, in initialize
    self._setup_version_attributes()
  File "{HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py", line 2458, in _setup_version_attributes
    if self.server_version_info[0] not in list(range(8, 17)):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Versions:

```
conda list -f sqlalchemy
# packages in environment at {HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
sqlalchemy                1.3.19           py37h7b6447c_0    anaconda

conda list -f pandas
# packages in environment at {HOME}/.conda/envs/test_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    1.1.3            py37he6710b0_0    anaconda
```

I am hoping for some sort of solution that allows me to keep using `sqlalchemy.create_engine` since it is needed for multiple calls to `pd.read_sql` and `pd.write_sql`

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I ended up using was to just switch drivers to the Microsoft provided driver: `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. Doesn't exactly solve the problem if you're stuck with FreeTDS, but it unblocks me.

e.g.

```
import sqlalchemy
DRIVER='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{USER}:{PASS}@{DB_SERVER}/{DB_NAME}?driver={DRIVER}")
```

Sample `odbcinst.ini`:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```